# Bitcoin Blockchain - Verification process

Tags: cryptography, bitcoin, blockchain

As the title states, basically my question is about the blockchain verification. I know whats a block chain and basically understood how mining is working, except once simple thing.

Let's say we have 2 guys, Bob and Adam.

```
Blockchain:

    |1|-|2|-|3|-{4}   - Bob Chain
    |1|-|2|-|3|-{4}   - Adam Chain
```

Assume both Bob and Adam found a new block, but it will not be verified until **someone** finds a next block. So my questions is whats is happening in a situation if Adam will find a block |5| first. Will Bob get his reward for finding a block? Or it means if Adam found one block, he has to find the next one which is extremely difficult without a huge network of computational resources in order to verify his previous block |4| and get reward for block 4 of 12.5 bitcoins, because the nodes will only accept the longest blockchain? I hope I clearly illustrated the picture. I've tried to find the answer in different videos and materials but somehow this aspect was put aside. If my assumption is true, it means there is no way how can a single person to earn anything from mining without a huge network ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming / development in itself; try https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in Bitcoin when someone creates a block, he broadcasta it to the rest ot the network. As you said, if there are two people that create the block at the same time, they will broadcast it. So, you will get two blocks at the same time. Although you save both blocks, you will try to mine one of them. After some time, one of the two branches will be longer, so you will delete the second one.

- The miners of the Blockchain will create some blocks and a branch will be longer after some time.

In Blockchain, a block is considered well when it has 100 blocks (I d0n't know exactly how many) above of it. So, the reward is taken after 100 blocks, not before.

Answer (score 0):

Who out of Adam or Bob gets the reward depends on whose block remains as part of the 'Best chain' eventually. This in turn partly depends on consensus rules and partly on how the things transpired. This is explained as follows

- Adam and Bob claimed that they found the block first by broadcasting to peers almost at same time.
- Let's presume that a peer named 'ITWala' saw these 2 blocks which would be at same height. Assuming Adam's block reached ITWala's node first. So this would lead to something known as 'forking' in block chain terminology and is quite normal to occur.

> **Chain status on ITWala's node leading to forking **

```
 Block1 --> Block 2 --> Block 3 --> Block 4 (Adam's Block)
                                |
                                |--- Block 4   (Bob's Block)
```

One of following can happen:
**Case 1** - For sake of simplicity, assume that Bob is the only one making claim for block 5. Now 'ITWala' receives block 5. He tries to make the chain longer by trying to fit at one end of the fork created from Block 4 from Adam. It does not fit because the hash of the previous block would not match.
**Result** 
Fork at the end of Adam's block is discarded. Fork with Bob's block becomes active chain and thus Bob becomes the winner of 4 as well as 5 for award.

**Case 2:**
Block 5 is created by 'ITWala' or some peer of ITWala who synced up with copy on ITWala's node.
**Result**: In this case, ITWala would use Adam's block to activate the best chain as it arrived first making him the winner for block 4. Block 5 is awarded to ITWala

There can be more combinations. However point here is that the block that remains in best chain wins the award.